# What's with this up-tilted head posture?

Tags: tropes, monogatari-series

In Bakemonogatari, we see Araragi (and possibly some other characters) at quite a number of times in the series with his head tilted upwards, in what would in real life be a somewhat uncomfortable angle. While this in a number of cases could just be a result of the "camera" angle, it's clear at some points that it isn't (e.g. Senjougahara in the last episode, in this screenshot).

[image: Senjougahara with tilted head]

Is there any "meaning" to this posture, other than possibly it being an artistic idiosyncrasy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's known as the 'Shaft head tilt' as the animation studio "Shaft" are well known for including it in their shows:

[image: Madoka] [image]
[image: Arawaka under the bridge]

Above are other shaft shows; Puella Magi Madoka Magica ,Arakawa Under the Bridge
, Nisekoi.

Anime director of Shaft since 2004, Akiyui Shinbo is responsible for this studio trait.

[knowyourmeme - Shaft Head Tilt](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/shaft-head-tilt)

The tilt is merely artistic, with no special meaning. Along with this, Shaft have other signature style traits such as large expansive empty rooms for dramatic effect and fast displaying text.

[image]
[image]
(who needs all that space to brush their teeth or have a bath?)

[TVTropes Shaft Studio](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/StudioShaft)

Comment: I would absolutely LOVE to have that much space in my rooms! So great for letting your feeling of realism go.